# Glitch when using check mark unicode with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visual-glitch

I'm just trying to use a check mark symbol (✓ - U+2713), but it gives me a glitch.
I'm using AGG backed graphic device.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.3

ggplot(x = 1, y = 1)+
  annotate("text", 
           x = 1, y = 1,
           label = paste("\u2713"),
           size = 10)
```

The plot works here.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

But I got it on my computer:
[image]

Comment: Interesting. I checked it on my computer and I don't have the glitch.

Comment: @BrunoMioto When you say that you're "using AGG backed graphic device" do you mean you do `library(ragg); agg_png("file.png")` then (gg)plot followed by `dev.off()`?

Comment: I Installed the ragg package, and then `Tools > Global options > General > Graphics > Backend: AGG > Apply`.
I saved the plot with `ggsave()`